# Holomorphic mapping

Tags: complex-analysis

Another Practice Exam question:

Suppose that $f$ is a holomorphic function on the open disk of radius 5 centered at
$0$, and suppose that $f$ maps the closed annulus $\{f(z) : 1  \leq |z|\leq  2\}$ into the open unit disk. Prove that the restriction of $f$ to $D (0;2) = \{ f(z) : |z| < 2\}$ has exactly one fixed point.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Rouché's theorem (Consider the zeros of $f(z)-z$).